# Pass variables from one page to a webform in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-webform

I'm trying to pass one variable from different product pages to a webform page. Each product page has a session variable like `$_SESSION["product_name"] = "Product1";`. Similarly, other product pages have `$_SESSION["product_name"] = "Product2";` `$_SESSION["product_name"] = "Product3";`

My question is how to pass these variables to a different webform page. I'm using "webform" module, what I want to accomplish is there should be a `<select>` tag, and there are options like

```
<select>
  <option value="<?php echo $_SESSION["product_name"]; ?>" selected><? php echo $_SESSION["product_name"]; ?></option>
  <option value="Product2">Product2</option>
  <option value="Product3">Product3</option>
  <option value="Product4">Product4</option>
</select>
```

The problem is there is no place for me to place these codes, is there any way around this or is there any module I can use for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom module and then implement hook_form__alter()

You would need to find the IDs of the webforms you want to target.

Then:

```
function mymodule_form_webform1_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    array_unshift($form['products']['#options'], array($_SESSION["product_name"] => $_SESSION["product_name"]));
}
```

or similar

Comment: Unfortunately, somehow it doesn't work with your codes. But you remind me to create a custom module, and you are right! I created a custom module to have a custom token, and the token takes the session value. I just use the token to be the default value and it works like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This might be a way to pass the session value to webform option default value. I'm using Drupal 7, Webform 4. The session values on different product pages are:

```
$_SESSION["j_product_name"] = "haha1";
$_SESSION["j_product_name"] = "haha2";
```

First I created a custom module, the .module part is(also need to create .info):

```
<?php
function jay_tokens_token_info() {
  $types['jay_token'] = array(
    'name' => t("Jay Tokens"),
    'description' => t("Jay custom tokens"),
  );


  $jay_token['product_session'] = array(
    'name' => t("Product Name"),
    'description' => t("product_name session value"),
  );


  return array(
    'types' => $types,
    'tokens' => array(
      'jay_token' => $jay_token,
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_tokens().
 */
function jay_tokens_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data = array(), array $options = array()) {

  $replacements = array();

  if ($type == 'jay_token') {
    foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
      switch ($name) {
        case 'product_session':
          $replacements[$original] = $_SESSION["j_product_name"];
        break;

      }
    }
  }

  return $replacements;
}
?>
```

In webform select options, the default value should be `[jay_token:product_session]` and options should be:

```
haha1|Product1
haha2|Product2
```